# GitHub Syncing a Fork Error

Tags: git, github

When I try to sync a fork with upstream via terminal it shows me some weird results. Has anyone faced this problem? Please guide me as what to do.

1. This Image shows up when I am trying to execute the command git merge    upstream/master the second time.
2. This window shows up when i execute the command git merge upstream/master for the first time and cant get rid of it
3. When I try and write something in it to save but nothing happens still
4. Finally have to stop it using control + Z but hardly works

[image: This Image shows up when I am trying to execute the command git merge upstream/master the second time]

[image: This window shows up when i execute the command git merge upstream/master for the first time and cant get rid of it]

[image: When I try and write something in it to save but nothing happens still]

[image: Finally have to stop it using control + Z but hardly works]

Comment: If there's no problem, just delete the swap file and perform the operation again (as it says in the error)

Comment: tried that still the same error

Comment: add `*.swp` to `.gitignore`. commit and push it to upstream. delete your local swap file and sync again.

Comment: How to add *.swp file because it is created when u try to merge the upstream in the .gitignore folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following keys to save :

1. Esc
2. Qq
3. Enter

Answer (score 0):

This is not to do with git, but rather vi. The default editor you're using, vi, was never quit (ctrl-Z just suspends it) and its swap file is still there. When you start it again, it detects this and asks you what to do. Just follow the instructions (probably <kbd>R</kbd> for recover) and proceed normally. To quit at the end, don't use <kbd>ctrl+Z</kbd>. Use <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

You should also consider changing your editor to one you know better. To do this, use `git config --global core.editor` followed by the executable of your preferred editor.

```
git config --global core.editor nano
```

Answer (score 0):

**Before you can sync your fork with an upstream repository, you must configure a remote that points to the upstream repository in Git.**

```
    1. Open Terminal.
    2. Change the current working directory to your local project.
    3. Fetch the branches and their respective commits from the upstream repository. Commits to master will be stored in a local branch, upstream/master
    4. If you don't care about applying also the eventual commits that have been added between the origin and the pull request, you can just rebase the branch on which the pull request was formed

Example: 

    $ git remote add upstream git://github.com/request-author/project.git
    $ git fetch upstream
    $ git rebase master upstream/pullrequest-branch


Congratulations !!!!
```